# How do I use Grequests on AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gevent, grequests

I have a `Lambda` function in `Python` that uses several libraries with binary dependencies: `numpy`, `scipy`, `Pillow`, etc. In the past, I have successfully compiled them on `Amazon Linux` & deployed to `Lambda`.

I recently added `Grequest` to the pile of dependencies, though, and it's throwing errors that don't seem direclty related to `Grequest`. [Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244563/unable-to-import-grequests-for-aws-lambda) on this topic have resulted in dead-ends, so putting my hat in the ring.

**The first error** was a simple `Grequests requires gevent` or something similar.  To solve this, I tried running `pip install gevent --no-binary :all:` on an `Amazon Linux` instance, bundling that with my code and uploading to Lambda.  This had no effect on the error.

**I then downloaded** the `src` from the `gevent` repo and compiled it using `make` (the commands in the repo's README threw errors I didn't record).  This produced an `egg` file, which I converted to a `whl` file & ran `pip install gevent.whl -t .`.

I bundled the resulting code with my `lambda.zip` and uploaded.  This led to a **new error**: 
`module initialization error: lib/libptf77blas.a.gz: invalid ELF header`

**`libptf77blas.a.gz`** is a file in the `lib` folder in my `lambda.zip`. This folder contains several `.so` and `.a` files, which I built on AWS Linux while assembling `numpy`, `scipy`, `Pillow`, etc.

As far as I know, this is a dependency for `numpy`. The part I don't understand is: my function used `numpy` (and presumably `libptf77blas.a.gz` just fine prior to adding `grequests`.

So I assume something about compiling `gevent` broke the dependencies for my other `binary`-dependant libs, or `gevent` itself requires `libptf77blas.a.gz` and is confused at what it finds.

I ran `ldd` on the `.so` files `gevent` depends on, but none referenced `libptf77blas.a.gz`. But, I'm a compiling newb, so that's hardly conclusive.

I'd like to achieve the parallel upload `Grequests` enables, but am unclear how to fix this, or which alternative libraries to use (I usually write JS, so Python is a second language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was entirely a stupid user error from an unrelated matter--follow the steps in the OP and you should be fine.

Or just use the copy of `grequests` [I posted on github](https://github.com/brandonmp/aws-lambda-grequests).  It's a `zip` with `grequests`, `gevent`, and `greenlet` compiled on an Amazon Linux instance.  It works in my `Lambda Function` just fine.

Comment: You should accept this answer even if it is your own as it is the correct one.

Comment: I know I'm replying to a year old post/answer but I'd be much obliged if you would happen to have the same kind of zip file for Python 3.6 :D

Answer (score 0):

As the [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244563/unable-to-import-grequests-for-aws-lambda) have stated, you need to make sure the binaries for [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) and other things, are compiled using the [Amazon Linux Image](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/). Basically, you need to install things like numpy, and Grequests on a machine running [Amazon Linux](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/) as they use C code that needs to be compiled.

The [tutorial link](http://www.perrygeo.com/running-python-with-compiled-code-on-aws-lambda.html) in that question looks quite good for building things from source, albeit a little bit more than you need for this.

If you're that new to compiling binaries you should read a bit about make, and look at some examples like [building curl](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-compile-and-install-packages-from-source-using-make-on-a-vps). Since you're on Amazon Linux, it uses yum and is quite similar to CentOS.

You *might* be able to get away with installing numpy and Grequests in a venv on a docker image in CentOS and zipping up the contents from that similar to the tutorial, but I'd first go with launching an EC2 instance using amazon's image and installing stuff there like the tutorial does.

Comment: thank you. as i note in my first paragraph, I've compiled numerous libraries on Amazon Linux before, including `numpy`, which up until adding `grequests`, worked fine in my `Lambda` function. I tried that tutorial you linked earlier, however the `gevent` library doesn't follow the same `make` steps, as far as i can tell. I was able to `make` the `gevent` repo into an `egg`, convert that into a `whl`, and install from the `whl` (on AWS Linux), but hit comparable errors to what my OP details. `gevents` also fails using less involved procedures, such as `pip install --no-binaries :all:`.

Comment: My apologies. I clearly glanced right over most of that first paragraph.

Comment: np--honestly I need to learn to write more succinct SO questions. It's unreasonable to expect people to dig out substance from my flowing prose :)

Comment: Just to clarify, running a `pip install grequests`, and testing the grequests lib itself on the EC2 instance produces this error as well, or is it just on Lambda?

Comment: The original `lambda` error is something like "Grequests requires gevent", so on Amazon Linux I installed only `gevent`. it failed at first as outlined in this [github issue](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/782), but after a few diff't approaches, the command `pip install gevent -t . --no-binary :all:` completes w/o error. But, packaging the resultant files into my `lambda.zip` does not solve the original error.  I'll edit my OP to reflect this, but it was building `gevent` from the `src` that got me from generic `Grequests requires gevent` error to the `ELF header` error (progress?)

Comment: i added some clarity to the OP re: the steps I've taken and the results they've had. thanks for your interest, @Kirk.

Comment: I'd try to get a sample script to run on the Amazon Linux image itself, just to be sure you got it compiled once correctly. Something dumb like https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests#usage just to make sure the thing works.  Also, it looks like the issue you linked seems to be a problem with pip itself. Perhaps something like `sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install --upgrade pip` would help out here too. You should be able to install the thing without being fancy with pip it seems.