# Unable to import grequest in AWS Lambda (Python 3.X)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, grequests

When I zip "grequest" and attempt to use it in a AWS Lambda function I get this error:

```
[ERROR] RuntimeError: Gevent is required for grequests.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/fiveDay_updater.py", line 11, in <module>
    import grequests as asyncReq
  File "/var/task/grequests.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('Gevent is required for grequests.')
```

It seems like others have had this problem. [Unable to import grequests for AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244563/unable-to-import-grequests-for-aws-lambda)
Unfortunately the solution proposed in the above link does not work for me.
Does anyone have a "grequest" zip that will work for the later python, or know of a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend an approach which has never failed me and is based on the docker tool [lambci/lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63239160/unable-to-import-grequest-in-aws-lambda-python-3-x) and creating [lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).

This has been described in the link below:

- [How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)

To **verify**, i created layer called `grequestslayer.zip` as follows:

1. Create folder `layer` and enter the folder
2. In the folder, create `requirements.txt` with content of

```
grequests
```

3. Runt the following command:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Zip the layer created:

```
zip -r grequestslayer.zip python
```

The layer will contain `gevent` automatically:

```
python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
├── bin
├── certifi
├── certifi-2020.6.20.dist-info
├── chardet
├── chardet-3.0.4.dist-info
├── easy_install.py
├── gevent
├── gevent-20.6.2.dist-info
├── greenlet-0.4.16.dist-info
├── greenlet.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
├── grequests-0.6.0.dist-info
├── grequests.py
├── idna
├── idna-2.10.dist-info
├── include
├── pkg_resources
├── __pycache__
├── requests
├── requests-2.24.0.dist-info
├── setuptools
├── setuptools-49.2.1.dist-info
├── urllib3
├── urllib3-1.25.10.dist-info
├── zope
├── zope.event-4.4.dist-info
├── zope.event-4.4-py2.7-nspkg.pth
├── zope.interface-5.1.0.dist-info
└── zope.interface-5.1.0-py3.8-nspkg.pth
```

5. Create lambda layer:

[image]

6. Add the layer to your function:

[image]

7. Use `grequests` in your function:

```
import json

import grequests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using a tool to deploy your functions, if you are not using a linux machine you'll face some issues to generate the zip. My recommendation for you is to use one of these tools to deploy your python functions on AWS.

- [Chalice Microframework for AWS](https://github.com/aws/chalice), this one is special because is a microframework for python supported by AWS.
- [Serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/)

Those are my recommendations for you so you don't have to deal with the zip generation manually, if you aren't interested probably you will need to use a linux instance to generate your zip.

Comment: So what is Chalice Microframework? I'm not sure how to use it..

Comment: It is a framework provided by AWS to write serverless apps using Python. You just need to define a virtualenv then install the library and all the libs you require, there are good examples here https://github.com/aws/chalice